# How to combine superslides.js and BackgroundCheck?

Tags: jquery

I have a website with a full screen slider (superslides script: https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides) and I have a logo on top of it.

I want the logo to change to a light color when a dark picture is behind it, and change to a dark color when a light picture is behind it.

I can do this with the BackgroundCheck script (https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check) but i don't know how to start combining it. I can't get it to work.

I had this script for the superslides:

```
    $(function() {
        $('#slides').superslides({
            play: 5000,
            animation: 'fade'
        });

    });
```

And this for the BackgroundCheck:

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
      BackgroundCheck.init({
        targets: '.logo',
        images: '.backgroundimages'
      });
    });
```

But the color change doesn't work, because it doesn't recognize there is a new image behind it, every time the slider animates...

In the documentation of BackgroundCheck is an example of how to combine with FlexSlider, but i don't get it:

```
   $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({
      animation: 'slide',
      prevText: '‹',
      nextText: '›',
      start: function () {
        BackgroundCheck.init({
          targets: '.flex-direction-nav li a',
          images: '.flexslider img'
        });
      },
      after: function () {
        BackgroundCheck.refresh();
      }
    });
  });
```

Is there someone who knows what to do and combine these two scripts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: A [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) if you can would be useful

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation for [superslides](https://github.com/nicinabox/superslides) and [backgroundcheck](https://github.com/kennethcachia/Background-Check), this 'should' work.. but not tested.

```
$('body').on('init.slides', function() {

  BackgroundCheck.init({
    targets: '.logo',
    images: '.backgroundimages'
  });

}

$('body').on('slides.animated', function() {

    BackgroundCheck.refresh();

}
```